# How can I add/remove cells in a table view more elegantly?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, model

I think this is probably an X Y problem, so I'll give some background info first.

I am building an app that can show a "form". The user can fill in the form with some stuff and create some custom things.

I think the most suitable thing to do is to use a table view for the form. And I can display all the text boxes that need to be fill in, in each of the table cells.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

The "Add New Input" button will insert a new cell on the bottom when it is tapped. And if you swipe one of the inputs to the left, you get a "Delete" button. You can use that to delete the input.

As you can see, this table view needs to add and delete rows.

Originally, I was using a cocoapod called "TableViewModel" which makes this super easy. But then I found [a really severe bug](https://github.com/tbergmen/TableViewModel/issues/1) in the library so I don't want to use it anymore.

I tried using the table view's `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` and `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` methods. But if I do it like this:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Hello"
    return cell
}

// I use motionEnded here because I don't want to add a button or anything just to test this
override func motionEnded(motion: UIEventSubtype, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
}
```

It will result in an exception saying that the table view is inconsistent with the data source after I deleted one row. This means I have to have code to handle this inconsistency. This will definitely make my code harder to read.

The same thing goes with the insert method.

Also, I need to keep track of how many rows there are in each section. And my code just becomes really messy and unmaintainable with all that.

I have also searched for other libraries but they are all really weird and not as straightforward as "tableViewModel". They all seem to require me to create a model for the table view. I don't understand how to do that in my case. I just want to display a bunch of text fields!

How can I insert or delete rows more elegantly? I think I either need to write an `extension` of the table view or learn to write a model for my table view. But I am able to do neither of these methods.

Comment: because you don't have any data source. Also see logically: suppose you add a new row with insertRowsAtIndexPaths . So now you have 2 rows. However your  numberOfRowsInSection always returning 1. so it will crash and vice versa for delete. Table view are supposed to work with a collection (NSArray, NSDictionary, NSSet etc.).

Comment: The thing, is that when you add or remove a row, you always say that there is only 1 row in the section. You have to use a Array or a Dictionary, to keep track of how many data (and which data) in each row and each section, and return that value in `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and `tableView:`numberOfRowsInSection:`.

Comment: You mean I should not do this kind of form using a table view? Then what can I do it with? @Alok

Comment: @Larme Yes I know. That's why I said it's not elegant. I need to add so much boilerplate. And it kind of  makes the code harder to read and maintain. I am asking how to do it in a way such that my code would be easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution!

I basically keep an array of an array of cells for the table view to display:

```
var cells: [[UITableViewCell]] = [[], [], []] // I have 3 sections, so 3 empty arrays
```

And then I added these data source methods:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return cells.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cells[section].count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return cells[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
}
```

Now, I can add and remove cells super easily:

```
func addCellToSection(section: Int, index: Int, cell: UITableViewCell) {
    cells[section].insert(cell, atIndex: index)
    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: section)], withRowAnimation: .Left)
}

func removeCellFromSection(section: Int, index: Int) {
    cells[section].removeAtIndex(index)
    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: section)], withRowAnimation: .Left)
}
```

With just two lines, I can add/remove cells with animation!

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't have any `data source`. Also see `logically`: suppose you add a new row with insertRowsAtIndexPaths . So now you have `2 rows`. However your `numberOfRowsInSection` always returning 1. so it will crash and vice versa for delete. Table view are supposed to work with a `collection` (`NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSSet` etc.).
For your help:

[Already they have nade a form as yours](http://manenko.com/2014/12/16/how-to-create-an-input-form-using-uitableview.html)

[obj-c easy to understand how table view with data source work](http://www.edumobile.org/ios/table-view-with-insert-and-delete-rows-in-iphone/)

[Adding, Updating, Deleting and Moving records using Swift.](http://rshankar.com/uitableview-demo-in-swift/)

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `TableView` to create the form but you must design an appropriate dataSource to keep track of these data. Now the dataSource method must be modified to

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return yourDataSourceForSection.count
}
```

You may edit this dataSource when a delete operation is performed as follows

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        //Delete the row from the data source to ensure consistency
        self.array.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    }
}
```

You may use a model class as the `dataSource`.

```
class NewCustomOperation: NSObject {
   var name: String?
   var rejectFloatingPoints: Bool?
   var inputs: AvailableInputs?
   var results: Results?
}

class AvailableInputs: NSObject {
   var name: [String]?
   var description: [String]?
}

class Results: NSObject {
   var name: [String]?
   var formula: [String]?
}
```

Comment: Yes I know that, but what would the datasource be if I have a bunch of textfields for the user to fill in, instead of a bunch of data to display?

Comment: Have you considered using stack views? Maybe a lot of work, but they would manage your interface for you super smooth.

Comment: @user3069232 but I am using iOS8 though, I don't think stack views are available.

Comment: Don't know what the plan is or requirement, but with IOS 10.0 just around the corner, you should upgrade to at least IOS 9.x, what's keeping you @ IOS 8.0 ?

Comment: I have added a model class as an example for your data source